# Clicking button to Dynamically add a field clears the already existing fields

Tags: javascript, html

Creating Dynamic new fields seems to clear the already existing fields

Also not trying to have multiple elements with the same id hence why i don't believe appendChild will work. Perhaps you can find a way to do that while creating different IDs?

Any help welcomed =)

```js
var template;
var a = 1;
window.onload = function() {
  template = document.querySelector("#wrapper").innerHTML;
  document.querySelector("#more_fields").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // tell the browser to not send the form
    document.getElementById('wrapper').innerHTML += template; // add next segment
    document.querySelector("#wrapper > label:last-of-type").innerHTML = "Segment " + (++a) + ":";
  });
}
```

```css
.form-group {
  display: inline
}

#wrapper > label {
  margin: 0 0 10px 210px;
}

.segment {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0 1em
}

.form-group > label {
  margin: 0 0 10px 20px;
}

.form-group > input {
  width: 15%
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2>Form</h2>
  <form>
    <div id="room_fields">
      <div class="content" id="wrapper">
        <label style:>Segment 1:</label>
        <div class="segment">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>IN:</label>
            <input name="seg-in[]" type="text">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>OUT:</label>
            <input name="seg-out[]" type="text">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Duration:</label>
            <input name="seg-dur[]" type="text">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br><br>

    <div style="text-align: right;">
      <button id="more_fields">+</button>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code works just fine, how does it clear the old fields?

Comment: I'll put it into a snipit so you can see what I'm talking about =)

Comment: Anytime you try to hit the plus button to add a new "segment/wrapper" aka dynamic element it clears the data form

Comment: Ok, I got your point now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`innerHTML` will not include the current value entered IIRC but it's still strange that doing `+=` operation will remove the existing value.

However, `insertAdjacentHTML()` should work as expected.

```js
  var template;
    var a = 1;
    window.onload = function() {
      template = document.querySelector("#wrapper").innerHTML;
      document.querySelector("#more_fields").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // tell the browser to not send the form
        document.getElementById('wrapper').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', template); // add next segment
        document.querySelector("#wrapper > label:last-of-type").innerHTML = "Segment " + (++a) + ":";
      });
    }
```

```css
.form-group {
  display: inline
}

#wrapper > label {
  margin: 0 0 10px 210px;
}

.segment {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0 1em
}

.form-group > label {
  margin: 0 0 10px 20px;
}

.form-group > input {
  width: 15%
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Form</h2>
    <form>
      <div id="room_fields">
        <div class="content" id="wrapper">
          <label style:>Segment 1:</label>
          <div class="segment">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>IN:</label>
              <input name="seg-in[]" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>OUT:</label>
              <input name="seg-out[]" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Duration:</label>
              <input name="seg-dur[]" type="text">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <br><br>

      <div style="text-align: right;">
        <button id="more_fields">+</button>
      </div>
      <br>
      <br>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, my below code is not 100% correct, you should alter it by yourself following mine.

In the HTML, you can define a hidden div which is your wrapper. In its and nested element ids, you can set a pattern like '$$$'.

```
   <div class="content" id="wrapper$$$" sytle="visibility: hidden;">
      <label style:>Segment 1:</label>
      <div class="segment">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>IN:</label>
          <input name="seg-in[]" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>OUT:</label>
          <input name="seg-out[]" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Duration:</label>
          <input name="seg-dur[]" type="text">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

In your javascript, declare a global variable named index and replace index value with '$$$'. It will be increased 1 when you add your template dynamically.

```
  template = document.querySelector("#wrapper").innerHTML;
  template = template.replace('$$$', index);
  index ++;
 ...
```

Answer (score 1):

**Problem:**

The problem here is with using `innerHTML`, because `innerHTML` will always override the HTML of your elements so previously typed values will be cleared, that's why you should use `.appendChild()`.

And your logic for dynamic is correct, you just need to chnage the way you add new fields.

**Solution:**

I tried to rewrite your code so it uses `appendChild()` in a smart way using the `#wrapper` `innerHTML` as template and updating the `id` dynamically in the new appended fields.

```
var template = document.querySelector("#wrapper").innerHTML;

function addFields() {
  var wrapper = document.createElement("div");
  wrapper.innerHTML = template;
  wrapper.querySelector("label:last-of-type").innerHTML = "Segment " + (++a) + ":";
  document.getElementById('wrapper').appendChild(wrapper);
}
```

This code will create a new `div` everytime, wher we put the `template` HTML inside it, update the `label` dynamically referring the label inside our current wrapper div using `wrapper.querySelector("label:last-of-type")`, then finally append this new div to our element.

**Demo:**

Here's a working Demo snippet:

```js
var template = document.querySelector("#wrapper").innerHTML;
var a = 1;

function addFields() {
  var wrapper = document.createElement("div");
  wrapper.innerHTML = template;
  wrapper.querySelector("label:last-of-type").innerHTML = "Segment " + (++a) + ":";
  document.getElementById('wrapper').appendChild(wrapper);
}

window.onload = function() {
  document.querySelector("#more_fields").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    addFields();
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2>Form</h2>
  <form>
    <div id="room_fields">
      <div class="content" id="wrapper">
        <label style:>Segment 1:</label>
        <div class="segment">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>IN:</label>
            <input name="seg-in[]" type="text">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>OUT:</label>
            <input name="seg-out[]" type="text">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Duration:</label>
            <input name="seg-dur[]" type="text">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br><br>

    <div style="text-align: right;">
      <button id="more_fields">+</button>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I ended up going with insertAdjacetHTML, and that seemed to work like a charm. Also thank you for the Note of preventDefault(), I'll take that out

Comment: @user3557933 Yes it may be a solution too, but take a look at the function in my edit it will make everything works great.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. It would seem that your code breaks after adding more than 2 segments...Also turns out e.preventDefault(); is a actually needed otherwise the form glitches out. Haven't figured out why but sometimes without the command it does not let you add more dynamic elements

Comment: @David I edited the answer, the problem was that we need to initialize `template` outside the function, so it will always have the initial content of the div. Actually this will fix all the problmes in your code and show you all the problems within it.